# Get the value of the A1 cell in Excel in a Visual Basic string

Tags: excel, visual-studio

I got a Visual Studio Windows Froms Application, and I want to set the value of the A1 cell from the Excel file "test.xlsx" to a string. So I can get that value to show in a label or textbox.

Comment: what is the name of the sheet from which you need the value? or does only one sheet exist?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. I'm just a beginner in Visual Basic.